# Booting from a cloned Windows 10 installation

Tags: windows, bootcamp, startup, external-disk

I have Windows 10 Pro installed on a external flash drive, I tried to install Windows via bootcamp but it is required to have more free space. I succeeded to install Windows 10 with VirtualBox on a SanDisk 32 gb flash drive and boot into Windows 10. The drive capacity is too small so I bought a Kingston Kyson 64 gb USB 3.2 flash drive, but it will not work with Bootcamp.

If I fresh install Windows with VirtualBox, the installation process will stop around 40% and reboot to EFI interactive shell.

If I clone SanDisk > Kingston from another Bootcamp machine, the clone drive will boot to Windows loading screen followed by BSOD.

If I clone SanDisk > Kingston from the booted Windows 10 drive, the clone drive will boot to Windows loading screen followed by Startup blue screen.

If I clone sector-by-sector, the clone drive will boot with BSOD 0xc0000225, 0xc000000e, Missing / Damaged Winload.efi.

Comment: In all cases I’m always booting Windows from Option (⌥) or Alt Startup Manager. I used VirtualBox only to install Windows 10 on a external disk, and succeeded to do so on the SanDisk 32 gb flash drive.

Comment: Windows really doesn't like being booted from an external drive, even on a regular PC. You need WinToGo for that to work properly (which I think MS have just abandoned as a product)

Comment: Is the drive faulty?

Comment: This is outside my area of expertise really, but have a look at https://twocanoes.com Basically, if it can be done, it can be done with something they make. Some of their tools are free, but not the main Winclone.

Comment: Humor me. Install the SanDisk in the USB port and post the output from `diskutil list`.

Comment: Maybe the drive is faulty or Kingston is not good for this aim.

Comment: This is the output from diskutil for the working Windows 10 disk or SanDisk 32gb flash drive:

~ % diskutil list
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *32.0 GB    disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:         Microsoft Reserved                         16.8 MB    disk2s2
   3:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                31.8 GB    disk2s3

Answer (score 1):

IMO, flash drives are not designed to endure the amounts of writes that would be performed by having an operating system installed on the drive.

There are many different mechanisms which can be referred to as having cloned. Since you have not explained how you cloned Windows 10, I will assume you are confident Windows 10 was correctly cloned. Windows does have the ability to detect when being cloned and if detected, can result in Windows 10 not booting properly. The general solution to this problem is to rebuild the BCD.

> I realize this answer is vague, but this is only do to the lack on details in your question.

Comment: EaseUS Todo Backup and WinToUSB will end both with the same results. I tried cloning in Legacy, VHD, VHDX and sector-by-sector modes. I am trying to restore in Command Prompt from booted Install DVD. I know it is not recommended but with SanDisk flash drive Windows 10 is more than fine.

Comment: If you can boot from a Windows 10 install DVD and open a Command Prompt, then why not just enter the commands to install Windows 10 on the kingston drive? Avoid cloning all together.

Comment: Yes please, I will install it this way but I am missing the commands. Also I tried all other commands such as BCD..., CHKDSK, SFC and registry hacks from the working Windows 10 external drive with no success.

Comment: I have a few thoughts. How old is your Mac? What model? I ask because you can use DVD's. I think the kingston is a Type A  5 GB/s (USB 3 = USB 3.1 Gen1 = USB 3.2 Gen 1) drive. Is this correct? What about the SanDisk drive? What did you have the virtual machine set for USB? USB 1.1, 2.0 or 3.0?

Comment: The main is an iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2015) with internal Bootcamp and the one in question is a MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2019) with external SuperDrive and Bootcamp. The SanDisk is a Ultra Fit USB 3.1 and the Kingston is a Kyson USB 3.2 Gen 1 with reading up to 200 MB/s.

Comment: I tested the Kingston Kyson USB 3.2 Gen 1 flash drive with Flash Drive/Card Tester v1.14 > Write/Read/Compare Test and it is not all Green, so it was faulty, also this is not the first time with this brand. I decided to go with Kingston because of Apple’s brands of choice before but I will never buy again from them.

Comment: Once you have a different flash drive, are you going to use your existing method to install Windows? Or, do you still what to know how to install using the CLI?

Comment: After the replacement I will test a refurbished WD WD3200AAKX 320 GB, 7200 RPM, SATA 6 GB/s, 16 MB Cache, 3.5 + USB 3.0 adapter/enclosure. I do not want to try with another flash drive, stick to HD, old but gold and also cheaper in this case. I will install Windows 10 from Virtual Box with custom settings.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using the VirtualBox method as long as all the hardware works after installing the Windows Support Software from Apple. If you have hardware problems, then you should consider using the CLI method. The difference is the CLI method adds some of the drivers to Windows before you first boot to Windows and the VirtualBox method does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this and your time is worth money so you can do other things, I recommend WinClone for this task.

1. It handles `sysprep` and [driver slipstreaming better than BootCamp IMO](https://twocanoes.com/knowledge-base/inject-applessd-driver-in-winclone-9/?seq_no=2).
2. It offers amazing support since it’s used by teams that run labs of dozens of Macs - so you’re not finding all the bugs and edge cases - they are and you have a product that’s battle tested.
3. It has [very good documentation on boot errors](https://twocanoes.com/knowledge-base/windows-boot-issues-after-winclone-restore/?seq_no=5) after [the restore](https://twocanoes.com/knowledge-base/resolving-inaccessible_boot_device-error-after-restoring-winclone-image/?seq_no=4).
4. It handles the cloning - which as you see - matters which path you take on that.
5. You still need to back up your Windows - so this can address both problems for you.

- https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone/